# Converting print output into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, economics

I am currently working on a world bank data project, and would like to convert the following output into a simple pandas dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
##If already have wbgapi installed, if not pip install wbgapi in cmd prompt
import wbgapi as wbgapi
print(wbgapi.economy.info())
```

Note, you may need to pip install wbgapi if you do not already have it.
I wish to convert the output of this print statement, which pulls up what is essentially a table, as then I can use pandas functions on this table, sortby etc.

I tried, what I was 99.9% sure wouldn't work as the output is ofcourse a string not a dict,

```py
economies = wbgapi.economy.info()
df = pd.DataFrame(economies)
```

Approaches such as converting a string to a list etc., I cannot figure out how to approach the string in question (the output of print(wb.economy.info())) given its spacing and column like nature, rather than being a block of text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does the return of `wbgapi.economy.info()` look like? You should add that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = wbgapi.economy.DataFrame()
```

I would suggest having a look at the documentation either way:
https://pypi.org/project/wbgapi/